# retrieving data from table that not have any id

Tags: sql-server

i have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    t.transactID,
    t.TBarcode,
    l.LocName,
    v.Vtype,
    t.dtime,
    t.PlateNo,
    ps.PS,
    pc.PlateCode,
    p.COMMENTS
FROM dbo.PoliceRecord_tbl p
INNER JOIN dbo.Transaction_tbl t ON t.PSID = p.PSource AND t.PCdID = p.PSCode AND t.PlateNo = p.PNumber
JOIN dbo.Location_tbl l ON l.Locid = t.Locid
JOIN dbo.VType_tbl v ON v.vtid = t.vtid
JOIN dbo.PlateSource_tbl ps ON ps.PSID = t.PSID
JOIN dbo.PlateCode_tbl pc ON pc.PCdID = t.PCdID AND t.STATUS IN (0, 1)
    AND t.TBarcode NOT IN (
        SELECT TBarcode
        FROM dbo.EmailSendLog_tbl
    ) AND p.DELETED = 0
END
```

my out put is getting correct:
[image]

but i have one more table EmailSubject_tbl that only contains one field [image] 
i want to get this value also while executing my query:
my expected output

```
Transactid  Tbarcode    Locname       Vtype    Dtime      PlateNo PS PlateCode Comments EmailSubject
3701      6191112123456 AddressHotel  Normal   2013-06-09  123456  Dubai  A     Test     PoliceRecord
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your EmailSubject contain one record

```
SELECT
    t.transactID,
    t.TBarcode,
    l.LocName,
    v.Vtype,
    t.dtime,
    t.PlateNo,
    ps.PS,
    pc.PlateCode,
    p.COMMENTS,
    (select TOP 1 EmailSubject FROM EmailSubject_tbl ) AS EmailSubject
FROM dbo.PoliceRecord_tbl p
INNER JOIN dbo.Transaction_tbl t ON t.PSID = p.PSource AND t.PCdID = p.PSCode AND t.PlateNo = p.PNumber
JOIN dbo.Location_tbl l ON l.Locid = t.Locid
JOIN dbo.VType_tbl v ON v.vtid = t.vtid
JOIN dbo.PlateSource_tbl ps ON ps.PSID = t.PSID
JOIN dbo.PlateCode_tbl pc ON pc.PCdID = t.PCdID AND t.STATUS IN (0, 1)
    AND t.TBarcode NOT IN (
        SELECT TBarcode
        FROM dbo.EmailSendLog_tbl
    ) AND p.DELETED = 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` to bring in an unrelated table:

```
SELECT
    ...
    p.COMMENTS,
    es.EmailSubject
FROM dbo.PoliceRecord_tbl p
....
CROSS JOIN dbo.EmailSubject_tbl es
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    t.transactID,
    t.TBarcode,
    l.LocName,
    v.Vtype,
    t.dtime,
    t.PlateNo,
    ps.PS,
    pc.PlateCode,
    p.COMMENTS,
   e.EmailSubject
FROM dbo.PoliceRecord_tbl p, EmailSubject_tbl e
INNER JOIN dbo.Transaction_tbl t ON t.PSID = p.PSource AND t.PCdID = p.PSCode AND t.PlateNo = p.PNumber
JOIN dbo.Location_tbl l ON l.Locid = t.Locid
JOIN dbo.VType_tbl v ON v.vtid = t.vtid
JOIN dbo.PlateSource_tbl ps ON ps.PSID = t.PSID
JOIN dbo.PlateCode_tbl pc ON pc.PCdID = t.PCdID AND t.STATUS IN (0, 1)
    AND t.TBarcode NOT IN (
        SELECT TBarcode
        FROM dbo.EmailSendLog_tbl
    ) AND p.DELETED = 0
```